# How do i make timer reset when user leave website

Tags: javascript, html

I've done a timer that counts up in javascript. The idea is to show the user how long it has been on the website. I want it to show the time regardless of when the user jumps between different pages on the website but when the user leaves or closes the tab it should be reset. My problem is that even if i close down the browser, it continues where i left it. 
JavaScript

```
var countDownDate = localStorage.getItem('startDate');
if (countDownDate) {
    countDownDate = new Date(countDownDate);
} else {
    countDownDate = new Date();
    localStorage.setItem('startDate', countDownDate);
}
// Update the count down every 1 second
var x = setInterval(function () {

    // Get todays date and time
    var now = new Date().getTime();

    // Find the distance between now an the count down date
    var distance = now - countDownDate.getTime();

    // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
    var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

    // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = days + "d " + hours + "h " + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ";
}, 1000);
```

HTML

```
<body>
    <p id="timer"></p>
</body>
```

Comment: This is happening because you are storing it in locaStorage. Is there any specific reason you are trying to persist it there. You anyways want to refresh it when user closes it.

Comment: Yes, change localStorage to sessionStorage solved it

Answer (score 1):

Change localStorage to sessionStorage solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use window unload api to clean up the things on last window close.

```
<body onunload="cleanUp()">

function cleanUp() {
  localStorage.setItem('startDate', null);
}
```

Comment: Or just use `sessionStorage` which is just like LocalStorage, but it does the cleanUp for you automatically

Comment: yeah!, I dont know his use case. If multiple window needed, sessionStorage won't work. It will work for tabs for sure.

Comment: even this setInterval will have issue, since multiple setInterval try to update same thing.. He has to use a worker for better performance.